# Drag and Drop File Not Working With Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, image, cloudinary

I have read a few articles but have not found any solutions yet,

I have a basic cloudinary setup with a Drag-N-Drop image upload, when I normally upload a file via file picker and upload it my cloudinary request works properly and I get all my info back like the image URL and more info, and I can see the images in cloudinary.

However, when I use the Drag and Drop feature the images show in the front-end but do not work on cloudinary and I get a empty array returned. Here is my JS for the Drag and Drop Functionality

```
container.addEventListener(
    "drop",
    (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        container.classList.remove("active");
        let draggedData = e.dataTransfer;
        let files = draggedData.files;
        imageDisplay.innerHTML = "";
        Array.from(files).forEach((file) => {
            fileHandler(file, file.name, file.type);
        });
        if (files.length > 0) {
            this.fileDropped.emit(files);
        }
    },
    false
);
```

Expected Output from cloudinary is something like

```
[
  {
    fieldname: 'image',
    originalname: '16691078151372291-9b8f80.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/deosogcvp/image/upload/v1681816378/Avanti/wve168hz4g3vnvlw3ew8.jpg',
    size: 5822,
    filename: 'Avanti/wve168hz4g3vnvlw3ew8'
  }
]
```

but my actual output is

```
[]
```

And also when I set the image upload field to 'required', the drag and drop feature does not work. I think my front-end js is not submitting the dropped files to the image store or something similar to that.

I just want to know how to get the drag and drop feature to submit the files and for it to work like a file picker

Comment: The [Cloudinary Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload) upload method would need to be explicitly invoked in the process. But [there are some documents](https://dev.to/johnpaul/drag-and-drop-image-uploader-using-react-dropzone-and-cloudinary-4a8n) available as a reference for your use case (e.g., in React project). Alternatively, you may also check out this reference - see [upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_let_your_users_upload_images_directly_from_facebook_dropbox_and_more).